# 'IF' in 'SELECT' statement - choose output value based on column values from order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in the table:
column one (insert_date), column two (update_date)

I need to order by `(if update_date> insert_date DESC)`

NOTE: default value for update_date id 0000-00-00

```
SELECT * FROM payment_release 
ORDER BY IF(update_date>insert_date) DESC OR insert_date ASC
```

Comment: Your intended logic is unclear.  Please add sample data which explains the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you try to achieve?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE payment_release (insert_date DATE, update_date DATE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO payment_release VALUES ('2022-10-05', '2022-11-02'), ('2022-10-12', '2022-10-08'), ('2022-11-01', '2022-11-11'), ('2022-12-02', '2022-11-26'), ('2022-10-17', '2022-10-27');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM payment_release;
+-------------+-------------+
| insert_date | update_date |
+-------------+-------------+
| 2022-10-05  | 2022-11-02  |
| 2022-10-12  | 2022-10-08  |
| 2022-11-01  | 2022-11-11  |
| 2022-12-02  | 2022-11-26  |
| 2022-10-17  | 2022-10-27  |
+-------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Test Code:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM payment_release ORDER BY IF(update_date > insert_date,"insert_date DESC", "insert_date ASC");
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| insert_date | update_date |
+-------------+-------------+
| 2022-10-12  | 2022-10-08  |
| 2022-12-02  | 2022-11-26  |
| 2022-10-05  | 2022-11-02  |
| 2022-11-01  | 2022-11-11  |
| 2022-10-17  | 2022-10-27  |
+-------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```